# Formatar valor Float como moeda usando Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma função que faz a soma de valores de uma linha, gostaria de saber se é possível colocar o valor como moeda assim:

```
R$ 16,00
```

Esta saindo desta forma

```
R$ 16.00
```

Mas não gostaria de usar biblioteca de terceiro.

Meu código:

```
var somaLinha = 0;
$('.columnRight  > label').slice(-5).each(function( i, coluna ) {
        var valorColuna = $(coluna).text().replace('R$', '').replace(',', '.');
        valorColuna = parseFloat(valorColuna);
        somaLinha += (!isNaN(valorColuna) ? valorColuna : 0);
});
if (somaLinha != 0) {
    $('.columnRight > label').last().text('R$ ' + parseFloat(somaLinha, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,")).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Sei que pediu em JQuery, mas JavaScript já possui uma função interna para isto. `Number.prototype.toLocaleString`

```js
var valor = 16.00;
var texto = valor.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});

console.log(texto);
```

Comment: Ja ouvi falar nessa solução, pelo que me parece os navegadores podem implementa-lá de forma diferente, você sabe alguma coisa referente a isto ?

Comment: Implementa da mesma maneira, só não funciona no Safari e em versões de navegadores mobile (exceto chrome). Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString

Comment: Até onde sei, este método usa a API de Internacionalização, a implementação dela depende do Browser, mas o resultado deve ser o mesmo, pelo menos não conheço casos de resultados diferentes dependendo do Browser, você pode consultar [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization) para ver que a Apple não gosta desta API.

Answer (score 7):

Bom eu achei como fazer, então segue a resposta.

```
function mascaraValor(valor) {
    valor = valor.toString().replace(/\D/g,"");
    valor = valor.toString().replace(/(\d)(\d{8})$/,"$1.$2");
    valor = valor.toString().replace(/(\d)(\d{5})$/,"$1.$2");
    valor = valor.toString().replace(/(\d)(\d{2})$/,"$1,$2");
    return valor                    
}
```

O parametro que eu passo é um valor float, e passo ele deste modo:

```
mascaraValor(valor.toFixed(2))
```

Comment: cara, como implementar este? não fez sentido para mim, não entendi muto bem, estou procurando algo assim pois no meu caso o replace normal não funciona, não sei por que

Comment: Vc vai criar este método na página e chamar no componente

Answer (score 7):

Você pode fazer assim, que também funciona:

```
function currencyFormatted(value, str_cifrao) {
    return str_cifrao + ' ' + value.formatMoney(2, ',', '.');
}

Number.prototype.formatMoney = function (c, d, t) {
    var n = this,
        c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
        d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
        t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
        i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
};

currencyFormatted(16.00, 'R$');
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que a soluçao do @Tobias Mesquita seja a solução adequada, mas eu pensei em uma outra maneira, simples de chegar no resultado esperado, então resolvi compartilhar.

> Segue:

```
Number.prototype.toBrl = function () {
   return 'R$ ' + this.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
};

console.log(parseFloat(16).toBrl()); // R$ 16,00
console.log(parseFloat(16.5).toBrl()); // R$ 16,50
console.log(parseFloat(0.4).toBrl()); // R$ 0,40
```

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso o sistema retornava no banco de dados o tipo "money" e a linguagem C# retornava para view o tipo "decimal".
Depois de muitos testes eu consegui retornar os valores formatados corretamente utilizando a seguinte função:

```
function formatReal(numero) {
    var tmp = numero + '';
    var neg = false;

    if (tmp - (Math.round(numero)) == 0) {
        tmp = tmp + '00';        
    }

    if (tmp.indexOf(".")) {
        tmp = tmp.replace(".", "");
    }

    if (tmp.indexOf("-") == 0) {
        neg = true;
        tmp = tmp.replace("-", "");
    }

    if (tmp.length == 1) tmp = "0" + tmp

    tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");

    if (tmp.length > 6)
        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

    if (tmp.length > 9)
        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1.$2,$3");

    if (tmp.length = 12)
        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1.$2.$3,$4");

    if (tmp.length > 12)
        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1.$2.$3.$4,$5");

    if (tmp.indexOf(".") == 0) tmp = tmp.replace(".", "");
    if (tmp.indexOf(",") == 0) tmp = tmp.replace(",", "0,");

    return (neg ? '-' + tmp : tmp);
}
```

Testado até com números negativos e retornaram corretamente.