# Formatar como moeda um input de um Form em html

Tags: html5, angular

Por gentileza alguém pode me ajudar, não estou conseguindo formatar um input como moeda.

```html
<label for="saldoInicial">Saldo Inicial</label>
<input type="number" format="currency" precision="2" id="valorSaldoInicial" name="valorSaldoInicial" class="form-control" formControlName="valorSaldoInicial" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript possui uma função interna para isto. Number.prototype.toLocaleString

```
var valor = 16.00;
var texto = valor.toLocaleString("pt-BR", 
     { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});

console.log(texto);
```

Fonte: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102582